# How to position button relative to parent?

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem with absolute positioning in my web page:

I want to position a button relative to its parent and this is what I did:

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.button {
  height: 55px;
  width: 180px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  background: url(Button.png);
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent" align="middle">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1900" width="1900px" />
  <div class="child">
    <button class="button">Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

This code makes the button have its position relative to the window and not to the image in which it is supposed to be, so when i zoom out or in the button moves inside the image, instead of having the same relative position.

Comment: Why image is having that much of width?

Comment: img does not act as container.

Comment: 1.) Kill align="middle" in the html. Use CSS.

2.) Kill width on image element. Use CSS. In simple cases don't use width at all - use the appropriate width image for the job.

3.) Explain what you mean by 'the button moves inside the image'. Should the image be a background image of the div?

Comment: there's no such width as 1900px in `img` tag. It should be `width="1900"` unless you 're using CSS styling where it should be `style="width:1900px"`

Comment: Also there's no `align="middle"` in HTML. There's `valign="middle"` (which doesn't apply in `div` but only in tables) or `align="center"`.

Answer (score 3):

i guess this is what you want to achieve

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/5KWeR/1/) is the solution `to your problem..`.

below is the updated css:

```
   .parent {
        position: relative;
   }
   .child{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left:0px;
   }
   .button {
       height: 55px;
       width: 180px;

       background-size: 100% auto;
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
   }
```

Comment: +1 for the solution, but please don't try to bypass the *add code* rule. It is there for a purpose. An answer with only link will lose its meaning if the link becomes inactive.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the positioning didn't work the way you want it to. And since you only wanted the image to be centered I did the following. I removed the position from the parent and changed the position on the image to relative. Then I positioned the button relative to the image. Try this:

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
    <img src="background.png" width="400px" />
    <div class="child">
        <button class="button"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent {
    text-align:center;
}
.child {
    position: relative;
}
.button {
    height: 55px;
    width: 180px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color:transparent;
    background: url(Button.png);
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position:absolute;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r4f2m/)